# Existence of a shift invariant selection map

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, existence-theorems

Some time ago I asked [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256450/shift-invariant-measurable-selection-theorem) question, but now realise that it is harder than I anticipated. Therefore I am taking a step back to the following problem.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets and $F$ a point to set map from the cartesian products:
$$
F: \prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}\left(\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} Y\right) \setminus \emptyset
$$
Let $\tau$ be the backshift operator on $X^\mathbb{Z}$ or $Y^\mathbb{Z}$, that is
$$
\tau(\ldots,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,\ldots) = (\ldots,x_{0},x_1,x_2,\ldots).
$$

> **Question:** Suppose that $F(\tau (x)) = \tau (F(x))$, where $\tau$ of a set is defined as the set of the shifted elements. Does there exist a map 
>   $$
> f: \prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} X \rightarrow \prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} Y
> $$
>   such that $f(x) \in F(x)$ and $f\circ\tau = \tau\circ f$?

Comment: You have to avoid the empty set, for otherwise $F(x)=\emptyset$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Let $R\subset \prod_i X$ be a set of representatives modulo shift, let $f:R\to \mathcal P$ be a choice function, i.e. $f(x)\in F(x)$, then extend $f$ invariantly.

Comment: Do you care about measurability?

Comment: Yes, I do. In my scenario, both $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces and I work with Borel $\sigma$-algebras. I will try to see if I can choose a measurable set of representatives and go from there.  Do you know of an approach to find a measurable $f$?

Comment: Then which measurable structure on $\mathcal P(\prod Y)$ do you consider?

Comment: On the product spaces $\prod X$ and $\prod Y$ I take the product $\sigma$-algebra. I don't have any measurable structure on the powerset, but in my scenario $F(x)$ is always a closed set in $\prod Y$. This allows, together with other assumptions, that I can apply a measurable selection theorem by  Kuratowski-Ryll-Nardzewski which ensures the existence of some measurable $f:\prod X\rightarrow \prod Y$ such that $f(x)\in F(x)$, but not necessarilly the shift invariant property. I've been trying to adjust that result, but have been unable to do so for now.